# Transforming numbers in a matrix structure into color squares

Tags: math-mode, formatting

Suppose we have a matrix of numbers

```
$$\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\    
1 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\   \end{matrix}$$
```

I would like to transform in MathJAx a matrix of numbers into the matrix where entries are color squares. The example of this could be the text **below** however it has a drawback that it has inserted vertical and horizontal spaces between squares.

How to do it without additional spacing? (to obtain continuous rectangular color area)

```
$\begin{matrix}
\color{red}\blacksquare \color{olive}\blacksquare \color{teal}\blacksquare \color{blue}\blacksquare \\   
\color{red}\blacksquare \color{olive}\blacksquare \color{teal}\blacksquare \color{blue}\blacksquare \\    
\color{red}\blacksquare \color{olive}\blacksquare \color{teal}\blacksquare \color{blue}\blacksquare \\  \end{matrix}$
```

Comment: Is this question really about MathJax or about something in TeX? Because MathJax tends to be off-topic here.

Comment: MathJax is not connected with Latex? Propose solution in Latex..

Comment: *No knowledge here* Does MathJax support `\color`?

Comment: Does it have to be in math mode or would a `tabular` suffice?

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, it looks fine except spacing is not needed.

Comment: @Skillmon If other solution is possible this could be taken into consideration ..

Comment: The colours are defined by the number in the cell? No calculation needs to be done to get the correct colour?

Comment: No, MathJax is far away from anything with LaTeX. For a LaTeX-solution you could follow Skillmon's approach, use a tabular, remove column separation and color the columns.

Comment: @Sillmon No, the mapping is fixed, only how to remove spacing between especially lines?

Comment: @Widawensen do you use that in a LaTeX document or only in a browser using MathJax? If the former you don't have to delete it, if the latter the question is off topic here, maybe using html would be better than MathJax (but maybe my code works in MathJax, I don't know).

Comment: In browser so far , however it would be good to know for the future, so I upvoted your answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcolumntype{\colored}{>{\collectcell\colored}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand*\colored[1]
  {%
    \ifcase#1
      \cellcolor{white}% if cell content is evaluated to be the number 0
    \or \cellcolor{red}%   1
    \or \cellcolor{olive}% 2
    \or \cellcolor{teal}%  3
    \or \cellcolor{blue}%  4
      % add more \or \cellcolor constructs for more colours
    \fi
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{*4\colored}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The white lines in the above image are rendering issues of `pdftocairo`. If you zoom 800 % with `xpdf` there are no seems.

If you slightly alter the definition of `\colored` (the macro not the column) you can even place stuff inside of your table cells (while still colouring them). If the contents start with a number, that number is considered to be the colour specification and the rest is typeset.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcolumntype{\colored}{>{\collectcell\colored}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand*\colored[1]
  {%
    \ifcase0#1
      \cellcolor{white}% if cell content is evaluated to be the number 0
    \or \cellcolor{red}\ifnum0<#1\fi%   1
    \or \cellcolor{olive}\ifnum0<#1\fi% 2
    \or \cellcolor{teal}\ifnum0<#1\fi%  3
    \or \cellcolor{blue}\ifnum0<#1\fi%  4
      % add more \or \cellcolor constructs for more colours
    % if the encountered number is greater than the defined ones \else is
    % used
    \else \cellcolor{white}\ifnum0<#1\fi
    \fi
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{*4\colored}
  0 different & content & is & possible\\
  1 foo & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The result is excellent. Nothing better I'm not expecting.